# Can we collect element's property when we tap using x,y co-ordinates in appium?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am automating an application which is DRM protected so I won't be able to take screenshot in uiautomatorviewer. That's why I approached for tapping action (TouchAction class) with x,y co-ordinates.

Is there any way around that after tapping on that element I can get some attributes value, i.e. resource-id, class or anything else which can help me to make things dynamic and smooth for other resolution devices as well.

```
new TouchAction(driver).tap(x, y).waitAction(time).perform();
```

I have added TouchAction code for better clarification. I would really appreciate all kinds of help.

Please feel free to put comments in case my question is not crystal clear.

Comment: Why do you want to get attributes value after clicking element?

Comment: After getting attributes values, isn't it possible to use that property to find element next time and then perform action?

Comment: I suggest you to use **Appium Desktop Inspector** to inspect your app and then find the automation id for the element. If any automation id is missing in your app, you can ask developer team to add it for automation.

Comment: The pain is I have no communication with developer and the second thing is it's DRM content so it doesn't work on Android Desktop Inspector too. I have tried that one already.